# How do I convert '\x80' hex to decimal

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am communicating with a servo using python's serial module. When I perform a `serial.read(1)` I get the value '\x80'. I need to convert this to decimal (128). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, never mind. I should have thought a bit. Googling `opposite of chr()` found me this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) in the python docs. And `ord()` does the trick.